# How to Create a Simple Series of Classes

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to programming, and I am trying to condense my code. 
I have a list of thumbnail links which appear in a series.

```
<div class="thumbHolder" id="thumb01"><img src="img/thumb_01.png" width="100" height="100" a/></a></div>
<div class="thumbHolder" id="thumb02"><img src="img/thumb_02.png" width="100" height="100"/></a></div>
```

I would like to condense this code so that I can create a series of links with an enumerated loop, where the modified div declaration might look like this:

```
// where x is iterated to a value equal to the total number of thumbnails
<div class="thumbHolder" id="thumb_" + x><img src="img/thumb_" + x + ".png" width="100" height="100" alt="title" + x/></a></div>
```

My research into loops has revealed some possible complications, but for an expert this might be simple? Any answers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Normally this would be done using the backend language, not frontend JavaScript. Is frontend JavaScript your only option?

Comment: use a client-side template engine

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers! I am using Java because I just took a class on it, and am excited to integrate it as much as possible, and I am not fully aware of the advantages and disadvantages of using it for particular functions.

Comment: Thanks Doodlebunch, I have had trouble finding a solution which does not include high-level functionality beyond my current skill level, and your supplied code looks really practical.

Comment: Thanks for the update Doodblebunch, my naming the instances with zeroes was to avoid an error that your solution prevents, and I will likely name them beginning with index 1 now, instead of 0 - great explanation! Tushar, your solution looks like it will function well also, especially once I start integrating more Java to my code in general.

Answer (score 0):

This loop iterates threw an array containing thumbnails writing HTML code to the document.

```
    aThumbs = [ 0, 1, 2 ]; // your array

    for ( x = 0; x < aThumbs.length; x++)
    {
       document.write( "<div class='thumbHolder' id='thumb_" + x + "'><img src='img/thumb_" + x + ".png' width='100' height='100' alt='title" + x + "' /></div>" );
    }
```

Since you did not open an A tag I removed the closing tag `</a>`

Note that this loop starts with index 0, if you want to start with index 1 do this:

```
for ( x = 1; x <= aThumbs.length; x++)
```

**[JSFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wfqfy4L4/)**

**EDIT:** I just noticed that you're using 
`01` and `02` in your HTML, is that the way you want to print the vars? The code given above inserts `1` and `2`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery like

```
 <script>
    for ( x = 1; x <= aThumbs.length; x++) 
    $( "body" )
      .add( "div" )
      .addClass("thumbHolder").attr("id","thumb_"+x).add("img").attr("src","img/thumb_" + x);
    </script>
```